# Android Camera Flash Timed Flicker error

Tags: android

I am trying to use a timer to create a flash flicker. But I am facing this problem; when clicking Button btn2, the flash turns ON then an exception is being thrown. The flash is turning on even though I have commented the cam.startPreview() line!!!
Any hints you can advice with according to this code: (Note: All variables were defined in the main class).

```
    btn2.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() 
    {   
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            Parameters p = cam.getParameters();
            p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
            cam.setParameters(p);
            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {                
                    public void run() { Flickering(); }}, 0, 1000);
        }
    });


    public void Flickering()
{       
    // Turn flash ON for 200 MilliSeconds
    btn2.setText("Flick");
    //cam.startPreview();
    /*
     * *****ERROR STARTS HERE*****
     */

    try 
    {
        Thread.sleep(200);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    //  e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Turn flash OFF for 300 MilliSeconds
    cam.stopPreview();
    cam.release();
    cam = Camera.open();

    try 
    {
        Thread.sleep(300);
    } 
    catch (InterruptedException e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        //e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Thank you in Advance.